# Configure incoming connection in amazon workspaces

Tags: amazon-ec2

I use amazon workspaces as a development machine. How can I configure a public IP to get incoming connections on this machine?

I tried configuring elastic IP to WS machine and defining security group allowing all incoming traffic from 0.0.0.0/0. Windows firewall is disabled.

What else can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to **successfully establish** a connection from the Internet to the Workspaces instance.

Here's what I did:

- Installed and activated a [simple web server](http://download.cnet.com/SimpleServer-WWW/3000-2648_4-14211.html) on the Workspaces instance
- Turned off the **Windows Firewall** on the Workspaces instance
- Located the **Elastic Network Interface (ENI)** associated with the Workspaces instance
- Created a new **Elastic IP address** and associated it with the ENI
- Opened port 80 in the **Security Group** associated with the ENI
- Pointed my web browser (on my own computer on the Internet) to the Elastic IP address

It worked! I was able to access the web page served from the Workspaces instance.

The hard part was tracing through the hierarchy of VPC, local IP, ENI and Security Group relationships.

Comment: Thanks, it appears that I used wrong ENI for elastic IP association. Now it works.

Comment: Great! If this helped solve your problem, please mark the Answer as correct.